# How does the Evangelion Rebuild series vary from the original?

Tags: evangelion

So after watching the Rebuild series for the first time a few years ago, and then re-watching it again after the announcement of 3.0+1.0, I'm wondering exactly how the Rebuild series varies from the original anime?

For example, the main identifiable difference is that the ocean is still red after the End of Evangelion, and instead of growing plants, Kaji is spending his time and effort filtering the sea to help repopulate/regrow the ocean life.

The other big difference is the events post "Third Impact".

What other differences are there in the series?

Answer (score -1):

To what I have read in comments and different posts is that rebuild is like an alternative universe. It has common events but they differ.
It intertwines with the alternative realities.

Asuka is more independent and not really into Kaji, she is not that weak any more.  No mental breakdown.
Kaji seems to still be alive. A whole different group is in the rebuild, Wille.
All the characters seem to have a stronger character.
Rei2 has more feelings.
No Jet Alone.
Some Angels are different and some appear differently from the original, different order of appearance, and there are new angels. Angels seem to be born from the Moon.
The time skip of 15 years.
Gendo going going to the Moon.
And some few more things.